# Only the first callback to complete stays alive

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, timer

My Issue:

When looping through a list of "RouteManager" class instances, I start a separate callback timer for each instance that handles routing images to a destination. These callbacks should run indefinitely, however only the first callback to complete stays alive. All of the other callbacks end after there first run.

Background:

Currently, I am trying to route images to multiple destinations (workstations) and have created a "RouteManager" class that handles all of the details of moving the images to each destination. I call the database and retrieve all of the active destinations and build a list of route manager instances. I loop through these instances and start up a callback timer that routes blocks of images if they are available. Below are the relevant blocks of code I am using to accomplish this task.

Main:

```
List<RouteManager> routeManagers = new List<RouteManager>();
var activeDestinations = dbQuery.GetActiveDestinations();

foreach (string activeDestination in activeDestinations)
{
       RouterConfiguration routerConfig = 
dbQuery.GetRouteConfigInfo(activeDestination);

       RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager(routerConfig);
       routeManagers.Add(routeManager);
}

Parallel.ForEach(routeManagers, routeManager =>
{
    var local = routeManager;
    local.StartRouteScheduleMonitor(1000);
    local.StartRoutingStudies(5000);
    local.StartUpdatingRouteStatus(5000);
 });

Console.ReadLine();
```

RouteManager Class:

```
private int _routeScheduleInterval;
private static System.Threading.Timer routeDequeueTimer; 

private static EventWaitHandle routingHandle = new 
ManualResetEvent(initialState: true);

public void StartRoutingStudies(int interval)
{            
    _routeDequeueInterval = interval;
    var callBack = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(RouteStudies);
    routeDequeueTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(callBack, null, 
interval, Timeout.Infinite);
}

public void RouteStudies(object state)
{
    routingHandle.WaitOne();

    RouteImagesSequential(_DestinationName).Wait();
    routeDequeueTimer.Change(_routeDequeueInterval, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Expected Behavior:

Each class instance should call its internal "RouteImagesSequentially" method until completion, wait 5 seconds, and firing again ad nauseam.

Comment: Did you mean to do `static` there?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Doh! Thanks, I missed that. I really need some more sleep and/or coffee. As expected, removing the statics solved the issue.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError If you will add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: We'll just have it closed as a minor issue.